# Is it possible to quantize a Tensorflow Lite model to 8-bit weights without the original HDF5 file?

Tags: tensorflow, google-coral

I'm trying to compile a tflite model with [the edgetpu compiler](https://coral.ai/docs/edgetpu/compiler) to make it compatible with Google's Coral USB key, but when I run `edgetpu_compiler the_model.tflite` I get a `Model not quantized` error.

I then wanted to [quantize the tflite model](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/post_training_quantization) to an 8-bit integer format, but I don't have the model's original .h5 file.

Is it possible to quantize a tflite-converted model to an 8-bit format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@garys unfortunately, tensorflow doesn't have an API to quantize a float tflite model. For post training quantization, the only API they have is for full tensorflow models (.pb, hdf5, h5, saved_model...) -> tflite. The quantization process happens during tflite conversion, so to my knowledge, there isn't a way to do this